# Microsoft Visual Studio "error cs0103: the name"

Tags: visual-studio-2022

I'm getting this error in Microsoft Visual Studio when using a textbox in the code behind.

`Error  CS0103  The name 'tb_dt_inic' does not exist in the current context`

The textbox exist's in the *.aspx file:

It's suggested when I type in the code behind but still getting the error!

`https://i.stack.imgur.com/05fSI.png`

`https://i.stack.imgur.com/9XISV.png`

`https://i.stack.imgur.com/fCXFT.png`

Is it a bug or am I missing something?

Already check I have the latest Microsoft Visual Studio Version (17.4.4).

Comment: Maybe you missed some include in the code? Some information is missing.

Comment: This page has almost 15000 lines (of codebhind), dozens of texbox's and it just happens with this one!

Comment: The only thing I would tell you is to clean the solution and compile again. or that you change the name or regenerate the textbox (maybe the problem is in the way you have created the grid or elements). But of course, I suppose this has already been done. But you will understand that without seeing more code it becomes difficult to detect the problem. Sorry I can't help you more.